# C/C++ mangle exports in a specific way

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

Due to specific needs i need to create a DLL which exports a function that is named in a specific way, it's also mangled.

```
?drawGdi@stop@234@@Z
```

Is there anyway of accomplishing this?

Comment: Give it any name that has that same number of characters, the modify the name in the final DLL executable with a low-level file editor. I suggest `XdrawGdiXstopX234XXZ`. Then just change the X's.

Comment: Ah, clever, I'll try that out :)

Comment: Be careful -- C++ ABIs do not always agree with each other, and symbol name are just one way they disagree.

Comment: What exactly are the *specific* needs motivating that question??

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but you have to write a DEF file.

## foo.h:

```
extern "C" declspec(dllexport) void foo(int);
```

## foo.def:

```
EXPORTS
    ?drawGdi@stop@234@@Z=_foo
```

(`_foo` is the exported name of the function).

Remember to specify the DEF file when linking the DLL, of course.

For more details see the [documentation on DEF files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx).

Comment: As mentioned in the URL you gave..."There are THREE methods for exporting a definition, listed in recommended order of use:
The __declspec(dllexport) keyword in the source code
An EXPORTS statement in a .def file
An /EXPORT specification in a LINK command". DEF file are only one of the available method! And additionally, the second choice!

Comment: @mox: Yes, but that's to simply export a symbol. According the document, the DEF file is the only one that allows you to specify the `internalname` different from the `externalname`.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012, tried to compile using `extern "C" declspec(dllexport) void foo(int);` but it doesn't want to work, so I changed it to `extern "C" void foo(int);` and my .def files looks like `EXPORTS
?drawGdi@stop@234@@Z=foo` however the export becomes `?drawGdi` leaving the rest off.

Comment: Try enclosing it in quotes, as in `"?drawGdi@stop@234@@Z"=foo` ?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you declare your function like e.g.

```
 class myclass;
 extern "C" void my_function(int,myclass&);
```

Then it should be exported as `my_function` (at least on Posix systems; I guess it is the same on Windows, but I don't know).

If compiling with GCC, you could use [Asm Labels](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html). Then any name acceptable by the assembler should be ok.

On Linux with ELF executables you probably could not, as David Schwartz suggested, simply edit the binary file (because that would probably break some hash-table used in ELF for symbols).

Comment: It needs to be exactly the name I wrote, it doesn't seem to allow '@' and '?' in the name

Comment: @EricLindgren: Windows does not allow `?` in filenames. It's not a problem of C/C++ but Windows.

Comment: when I see `std::string` in a exported function of a DLL there's a **red flag** raised in my mind: **Danger !** cf. this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564985/returning-stdstring-stdlist-from-dll

Comment: That `std::string&` was only an example. Propose any other C++ (but not C) type which is relevant for the discussion....