# Wrapping a c++ DLL using cython: all strings are empty

Tags: python, c++, dll, windows-7, cython

I'm trying to wrap a DLL written in c++ using cython. In the end I will not have access to the
source code, so the c++ source itself cannot be used in the process of compiling the wrapper, jus the `.dll`, the `.lib` and the `.h`.
All is compiling well.
However, I immediately found that strings are not behaving well.  For instance, dll
functions that return a simple string are not working correctly: the cython code always gets an
empty string.  I'm on windows 7. I've verified the following.

- The DLL has been build by Visual Studio 2015 (i.e. v 1900) with the 2015 toolset in debug
  mode. I tried both compiling with /MTd and /MDd flags. The resulting .lib and .dll file are
  put in the same folder as all other files below.
- My python 3.5 distribution has been built by VS 2015 as well, for 32 bit.

  ```
  $ python -iu
  Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
  ```
- When I compile with a dummy c++ source that contains such a function that returns a string,
  it just works. Using the dll it doesn't work.

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(
    "test.pyx",                 # our Cython source
))
```

test.pyx:

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: libraries = MyDLL
# distutils: include_dirs = .
# distutils: library_dirs = .
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from "MyDLL.h" namespace "somenamespace":

    int ReturnSomeInt()
    string ReturnSomeString()

def run():
    cdef string s = string(b'abcdefg')
    print(s)
    cdef int i = ReturnSomeInt()
    print(i)
    cdef string problem = ReturnSomeString()
    print(problem)
```

MyDLL.h:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int ReturnSomeInt();
__declspec(dllexport) std::string ReturnSomeString();
```

Snippet of C++ code that was used to compile MyDLL:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int ReturnSomeInt() { return 42; }
__declspec(dllexport) std::string ReturnSomeString() { cout << "debug..." << endl; return "Hello world!"; }
```

main.py:

```
from test import run
run()
```

I compile using the command

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force && python -u main.py
```

Running this prints

```
b'abcdefg'
42
debug... # printed by the dll function ReturnSomeString()
b'' # Should've printed: b'Hello World!'
```

We can verify that the ReturnSomeString() from MyDLL is actually called, as it sends some text to stdout.

What didn't I check?

Comment: My guess is that there is something DLL related happening, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797418/how-do-i-safely-pass-objects-especially-stl-objects-to-and-from-a-dll and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564985/returning-stdstring-stdlist-from-dll

Comment: Also [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797588/5781248) that hints that the compiler version and the settings have to be the same.

Comment: Those links are useful!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22797419/1546844) pointed to by @hakala I discovered that Debug/Release mode matters. It didn't enter my mind that it could. I quote:

> The C++ standard library has its own set of ABI issues. There is no
>   guarantee that a given STL type is laid out the same way in memory,
>   nor is there a guarantee that a given STL class has the same size from
>   one implementation to another (in particular, debug builds may put
>   extra debug information into a given STL type). Therefore, any STL
>   container will have to be unpacked into fundamental types before being
>   passed across the DLL boundary and repacked on the other side.

Indeed, compiling the DLL in Release mode made the example in the OP work.