# Correct use of shared_ptr to eliminate deallocation across DLL boundaries

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm reading "[Using shared_ptr in dll-interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605640/using-shared-ptr-in-dll-interfaces)". In that post, phlipsy suggested a way to pass no implementation specific object across DLL boundaries, at the end of his answer. Basically, the idea is to return a raw pointer from DLL and initialize the `shared_ptr` in EXE w/ that raw pointer.

I don't think it's correct. Let me reprototype it for simplicity.

```
// wrong version??
// DLL
Object* createObject()
{
  return new Object;
}

// EXE
std::tr1::shared_ptr<Object> p(createObject());
..
```

When `object` is deallocated, the destruction context/heap used by `shared_ptr` is different from that used in DLL during construction.

The right way to use `shared_ptr` is that resource allocation should be in the same line w/ the initialization of `shared_ptr`, so that the allocation and deallocation can use the same heap, as shown below.

```
// right version
// DLL
std::tr1::shared_ptr<Object> createObject()
{
  return std::tr1::shared_ptr<Object>(new Object);
}

// EXE
std::tr1::shared_ptr<Object> p(createObject());
..
```

Am I right?

Comment: You are correct.  Fingers crossed that both modules use the same CRT version.

Comment: In the linked answer, he clearly states that you bind a custom deallocation function to the `shared_ptr` when doing it this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right with both statements. A second correct way would be to return a raw pointer by createObject(..), initialize a shared_ptr with it and pass a custom deleter to the shared_ptr. The custom deleter is a library function like releaseObject(..).

Edit:
With your version (createObject(..) returns a shared_ptr<..>) you're bound to a specific shared_ptr implementation of the library and the library user. In my proposed way this restriction is gone.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that allocating/deallocating memory should always be done from the same module.  Thus, you can create a shared pointer with an allocator that calls the correct deallocation method in the allocating module.

The rules that apply to raw pointers still apply, even if you've wrapped them in a smart pointer.