# Delete instance of class from DLL

Tags: c++, dll, smart-pointers, dllimport, dllexport

I am asking for help in implementing the proper freeing of memory in the dll library.

The structure of my project looks like this:

Library.dll:

- interface.h -> base class definition with pure virtual methods
- implementation.h -> derived class inheriting from public base
- implementation.cpp -> derived class methods definition

implementation.h contains also exported functions:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Base* __stdcall Create()
{
    return new Derived;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Delete(Base* B)
{
    delete B;
}
```

Apllication.exe code looks like this:

```
#include "interface.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

typedef Base* (*CREATE_BASE)();
std::unique_ptr<Base> SmartPointer;

int main()
{
    // Load the DLL
    HINSTANCE dll_handle = ::LoadLibrary(TEXT("Library.dll"));
    if (!dll_handle) {
        std::cout << "Unable to load DLL!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the function from the DLL
    CREATE_BASE Fn = (CREATE_BASE)GetProcAddress(dll_handle, "Create");
    if (!Fn) {
        std::cout << "Unable to load Create from DLL!\n";
        ::FreeLibrary(dll_handle);
        return 1;
    }

// i have possibility to use only C++11 so creation of unique_ptr looks like this:
SmartPointer = std::unique_ptr<Base>(Fn());

// ... do something like SmartPointer->Action();
::FreeLibrary(dll_handle);
return 0;
}
```

The code above works and I can easily initialize the Base object and perform functions from the Derived class. Now i would like to use the exported "`Delete`" function as a custom pointer deleter now. So I prepared the definition of the type:

`typedef void (*DELETE_BASE)(Base* B);`

and I would like to use it more or less like this:

```
DELETE_BASE DeleteFn=(DELETE_BASE)GetProcAddress(dll_handle,"Delete");
SmartPointer = std::unique_ptr<Base>(Fn(),DeleteFn);
```

However, I get a compiler error that this unique_ptr definition is incorrect. How to fix this?

My current solution is based on:

- [How to create a shared_ptr in dll and export it via a factory function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993563/how-to-create-a-shared-ptr-in-dll-and-export-it-via-a-factory-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the deleter function must be specified since you want to override the default deleter (refer to [std::unique_ptr<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)).

Where you have used:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base>
```

you would instead want to use:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base, DELETE_BASE>
```

Comment: As you suggest i made changes: std::unique_ptr<Base,DELETE_BASE> SmartPointer; and  SmartPointer=std::unique_ptr<Base,DELETE_BASE>(Fn(),DeleteFn); but i get compiler error: Static assert failed: 'unique_ptr constructed with null deleter pointer'

Comment: The `std::unique_ptr<Base, DELETE_BASE>` cannot be default-constructed, so move the declaration to the assignment, e.g., `std::unique_ptr<Base, DELETE_BASE> SmartPointer = std::unique_ptr<Base, DELETE_BASE>(Fn(), DeleteFn);`.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. It looks like it works but here a new question arises - as you probably guessed, my final implementation to support functions from a dll file is a bit more complex. The mentioned unique_ptr was supposed to be a member of another class, which contains functions that were to use it after initialization. In this case, when I declare and initiate at the same time it is not possible. Is there any way to store this pointer like a class member?

Comment: While not very elegant and I haven't tried it, I think you could wrap it in another `std::unique_ptr<>`, e.g., `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<Base, DELETE_BASE>> myMember`, which would allow default construction of `myMember`, then to assign it you would use something like `instance.myMember = std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<Base, DELETE_BASE>>(Fn(), DeleteFn));`.