# How can I clear error LNK2001 in VS2015 with Bullet Physics SDK?

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

PS. sorry.. I'm not good at speaking English.

I want to ask something about Bullet Physics SDK.
// I use Vistual Studio 2015 / Bullet 2.88

current my solution folder have lib files, header files

> for debug mode lib files :
>   BulletCollision_vs2010_debug.lib / BulletDynamics_vs2010_debug.lib / LinearMath_vs2010_debug.lib
>
> for release mode lib files : 
>   BulletCollision_vs2010.lib / BulletDynamics_vs2010.lib / LinearMath_vs2010.lib

and i did all setting like these

```
set inc Dir : Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories
set lib Dir : Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories
set additional Dependencies : Properties->Linker->Input->Additional>Dependencies
set appropriate runtime library : Properties->C/C++->Code Generate->runtime ilbrary
```

but I have still error in my project

`외부 기호를 확인할 수 없습니다. = unresolved external symbol`

> main.obj : error LNK2001: "public: virtual float __thiscall
>   btCollisionShape::getContactBreakingThreshold(float)const "
>   (?getContactBreakingThreshold@btCollisionShape@@UBEMM@Z) 외부 기호를 확인할 수
>   없습니다.
>
> main.obj : error LNK2001: "public: virtual float __thiscall
>   btCollisionShape::getAngularMotionDisc(void)const "
>   (?getAngularMotionDisc@btCollisionShape@@UBEMXZ) 외부 기호를 확인할 수 없습니다.
>
> main.obj : error LNK2001: "public: virtual void __thiscall
>   btCollisionShape::getBoundingSphere(class btVector3 &,float &)const "
>   (?getBoundingSphere@btCollisionShape@@UBEXAAVbtVector3@@AAM@Z) 외부 기호를
>   확인할 수 없습니다.
>
> main.obj : error LNK2001: "public: virtual void __thiscall
>   btConvexShape::project(class btTransform const &,class btVector3 const
>   &,float &,float &,class btVector3 &,class btVector3 &)const "
>   (?project@btConvexShape@@UBEXABVbtTransform@@ABVbtVector3@@AAM2AAV3@3@Z)
>   외부 기호를 확인할 수 없습니다.
>
> main.obj : error LNK2001: "public: virtual void __thiscall
>   btSphereShape::calculateLocalInertia(float,class btVector3 &)const "
>   (?calculateLocalInertia@btSphereShape@@UBEXMAAVbtVector3@@@Z) 외부 기호를
>   확인할 수 없습니다.

how can I fix these error?
thank you for listening!

Comment: I suggest you switch to English if you plan on programming more. Your errors will be almost unsearchable otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Are you sure the BulletDynamics libraries are [version-independent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600413/1771479)? Otherwise, you might have to recompile the library for VS2015.

Comment: @Passer By thank you for your advice. I'm trying again

Comment: @agold yes, I compile BulletDynamics with Visual Studio 2015 (v140)

Comment: to who read this because of same errors :
I finally cleared all errors!!

I used Bullet Physics SDK 2.88 ver, but I read QuickStart.pdf for 2.82.

I built libs(collision, dynamic, linearmath) with build_visual_studio_vr_pybullet_double.bat file in bullet3-2.88 directory. but it had errors that I encountered.

when I built with ver 2.82, there were no matters.(please look at 2.82's QuickStart.pdf to build project)
I thank everyone who answered! :)

Answer (score 3):

The error `btCollisionShape::getBoundingSphere(class btVector3 &,float &)` looks to me like you have **btScalar** defined as single precision but the bullet library will by default define **btScalar** as double precision by setting **BT_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION** = 1. You will need to do the same in your application to make sure the types are lined up.